# PHP & MYSQL Select dropdown not filtering correctly on all results

Tags: php, mysql, html-select, dropdown

I'm trying to make my select dropdown filter correctly on a MySQL query although to no avail. If a holiday date is equal to a stocktaking date, the worker should not be visible on the dropdown.

This works only for the first result of the row, below are some examples;

More examples;

- User A can't work 10/6/2019 so he doesn't show **(this is correct)**
- and User A also can't work 11/6/2019 but now shows for all dates. (this shouldn't be happening)

Another example;

- User A can't work 10/6/2019 so he doesn't show **(this is correct)**
- and User B can't work 11/6/2019 but now User A shows for all dates again. (this shouldn't be happening)

Another example;

- User A & B can't work 10/6/2019 so User B & User A don't show **(this is correct)**
- and User B can't work 11/6/2019 but now User A shows for all dates again. (this shouldn't be happening)

```
if ($available_date == $stk_date) {
    $query = "
        SELECT *
        FROM user_master
        WHERE id NOT IN (
            SELECT UM.id
            FROM user_master UM 
            JOIN bookings B ON B.id_item = UM.id
            JOIN stocktakes S ON B.the_date = S.stk_date
        )
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    // $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option value=$row[first_name]>$row[first_name]  $row[last_name]</option>'";
        }
    }
}
else {
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM user_master";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    // $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option value=$row[first_name]>$row[first_name]  $row[last_name]</option>'";
        }
    }
}
```

I need to figure out to make it so that;

If User A, B, C or D etc - can't work on 10/6/2019 - they don't show in any of the dropdowns for the 10/6/2019 row.

and if User A, B & C - can't work on 11/6/2019 - they don't show in any of the dropdowns for 10/6/2019 row and 11/6/2019 as they're marked as not working those days.

Here's some SQL Fiddles (first time using it, wasn't sure how to make multiple tables) in there is just the basic data that I'm using.

- Holidays - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/814d14/1
- Stocktakes - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cc05e/1
- Users - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a3ff6/1

**Update:**

I've noticed it seems to work if there's only one 'value' if that makes any sense, so for example;

- If I make User A booked on 10/06/2019 it works.
- But if I make User A booked on 10/06/2019 & 11/06/2019 it doesn't work.
- If I make User A & User B booked 10/06/2019 it works
- Although if I make User B booked on 11/06/2019 it doesn't work.

**Update 2:**

It 100% works as intended if there's only one row in the table - if a second row is added, it just doesn't work and mixes results up. Almost as if the query isn't running correctly for each row?

Comment: You would probably be better off doing the filtering after retrieving all the results. So filter the results via the code instead of the query.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for the idea - I've tried doing it through the code although my knowledge of doing that isn't as good as it is using SQL. Any pointers on where to start?